# how to configure plugin in Nagios?

Tags: tomcat, nagios

I try to install plugin in ubuntu for monitor tomcat i download plugin file from

> http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Java-Applications-and-Servers/Apache-Tomcat

but how to configure this plugin in nagios-server so i can monitor tomcat using web-console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to flesh out Priya's answer a bit, and add some insights from my own ordeal with getting this plugin to work.

The main issue I had was related to ePN (embedded Perl Nagios): apparently the plugin does not comply with ePN's standards and, after having successfully run the script from the command line, I kept getting this error:

```
**ePN /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_tomcat: "Subroutine LWP::UserAgent::get_basic_credentials redefined at (eval 1) line 222,".
```

I searched for disabling ePN globally, but found this [Nagios doc page](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/embeddedperl.html) with this helpful advice:

> To tell Nagios to NOT use the embedded Perl interpreter for a
>   particular script, add this line to the Perl script:
>
> `# nagios: -epn`
>
> Either line must be located within the first 10 lines of a script for
>   Nagios to detect it.

Adding that comment cleared up "UNKNOWN" error, and the plugin started working.

**Installing**

I installed Nagios through the EPEL repository.  I've left most permissions the same as they were installed, including the plugins which were installed as `root:root`.  The one change I did make was to change all the `CFG` files in `/etc/nagios/objects` to `root:nagios`: I added myself to the `nagios` group, and so editing is much easier.  For my CentOS installation, plugins are installed to `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins`.  I downloaded `check_tomcat.pl` to that directory, renamed it to just `check_tomcat` (for no real good reason), did a `chmod 755` on it, and added `# nagios: -epn` to it.

Here are the excerpts from my `CFG` files:

**commands.cfg:**

```
# 'check_tomcat' command definition
define command{
       command_name check_tomcat
       command_line $USER1$/check_tomcat -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p $ARG1$ -l $ARG2$ -a $ARG3$ -w $ARG4$ -c $ARG5$
       }
```

**localhost.cfg:**

```
# Define a service to check the state of a Tomcat service
define service{
       use                  local-service
       host_name            localhost
       service_description  Tomcat
       check_command        check_tomcat!8080!tomcat!tomcat!25%,25%!10%,10%
       }
```

`$HOSTADDRESS$` is passed as the `host_name` alias from the service to the command.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

1. After Downloading the plugin move this plugin to the plugins folder by efault its /usr/local/nagios/libexec/.
2. Change the permission of the plugin to nagios

   ```
   chown nagios:nagios /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_tomcat.pl
   ```
3. Add the command definition for this plugin in command.cfg file.Location(/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg)

   ```
   define command{
   command_name check_tomcat
   command_line /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_tomcat.pl
   }
   ```

   Mention the arguments you need for the plugin
4. Add the command in your service file may be localhost.cfg or a separate file.

   ```
   define service{
   use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
   hostgroup_name                  Host1
   service_description             Tomcat
   check_command                   check_tomcat
   contacts                        contact1
   notifications_enabled           1
   }
   ```
5. Restart the nagios and xinetd (if you use)

Now you can view the service monitoring tomcat in your web console.